# Dynamically load a class in java

Tags: java, class

Here is my classes.

```
package com.psu.janibot;

public class Janibot implements Runnable {

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("move");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Janibot janibot = (Janibot) Class.forName("Janitor").newInstance();
            janibot.run();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

import com.psu.janibot.Janibot;

public class Janitor extends Janibot {
    public void run() {
        move();
    }
}

package com.psu.janibot;

public class Janitor2 extends Janibot{
    public void run() {
        move();
    }
}
```

if i type >java Janitor it will run the Janitor class
if i type >java Janitor2 it will run the Janitor2 class

I want to do is to run Janitor or Janitor2 without typing the class name in forName method like this Janibot janibot = (Janibot) Class.forName("Janitor").newInstance();

Comment: what do you mean  " without typing the class name"?

Comment: OK.  Did you have a question?

Comment: how do you expect to load a class without knowing what class you want to load?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do you can also use reflection (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html) to call a particular constructor.

Comment: @HotLicks do you know karel the robot? i want to make like karel the robot. i want to run the program without seeing the main method.

Comment: But did you have a question?  (And asking me if I know "karel the robot" is not a legitimate question for SO.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class.forName()` takes a String as a parameter, so you need to pass it somehow, so I presume you mean not hard coded.

Pass the String in as the arguments to the program and read them from the args array

```
java Janibot Janitor
....
Class.forName(args[0]).newInstance()
```

Other options exist such as read from file, using a Scanner, etc.